# Apache Storm S3 bolt

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-storm

My requirement is to store log files periodically in S3, We are using Storm and Kafka. Challenge is I am getting logs in JSON format through Kafka, need to create file of that object, then after every specific time interval need to collect all files, zip it and store it on S3.
If some one has done this before, please share.
Other alternatives also welcome for this requirement.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get all object for X minute duration
2. Store them in NoSql database
3. Other bolt triggers zipping and uploading to S3 for every X minute expiry
4. Clear Db for that X minute